# How to make custom text appear underneath each bar in chartjs bar chart?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

In chart js bar chart is it possible to have custom text exactly under each bar ? in below images the first one correct and second one is not.
[image]

[image]

You can check demo here [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-feather-cwxjb?file=/src/MyChart.js)

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand why you want to repeat the labels on the xAxes but this can be done with the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In your case, you can use the `afterDraw` hook to draw text directly on the canvas.

The plugin would be defined as follows:

```
const plugins = [{
  afterDraw: chart => {
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    ctx.save();
    var xAxis = chart.scales["x-axis-0"];
    var yAxis = chart.scales["y-axis-0"];
    xAxis.ticks.forEach((v, i) => {
      var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(i);
      var value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[i];
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.font = "18px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = value < 0 ? "#fc3e78" : "#53b300";
      ctx.fillText(value, x, yAxis.bottom + 80);
      ctx.fillText(likeslabels[i][0], x, yAxis.bottom + 100);
    });
    ctx.restore();
  }
}];
```

Then tell the `Bar` element about the plugin to be used.

```
<Bar
      ref={barRef}
      data={likesdata}
      plugins={plugins}  // add this line
      width={75}
      height={20}
      options={likesoptions}
/>
```

Also add some extra space at the bottom of the chart by defining [`layout.padding.bottom`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html) inside the chart options, otherwise the text won't be visible.

```
const likesoptions = {
  layout: {
    padding: {
      bottom: 60
    }
  },
```

Please have a look at your amended [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-haze-lkrfm?file=/src/MyChart.js:2011-2098).